# Gtk api to find bookmarks location in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, nautilus

I would like to know if there exists an API and also a command to find the bookmarks file name and path in ubuntu.

My application writes to the bookmarks file to add some short cuts. Before ubuntu 11.X the bookmarks file used to be in "/home/myname/.gtk-bookmarks", but post ubuntu 13.0X it is inside "/home/myname/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks". If I have to support my application for all versions of ubuntu, then I must not rely on hard coding the path of bookmarks file name/path. Is there an, API and command to find out the path and name of a bookmarks file? (I want a command also because I want to invoke it from a script as well).

Nautilus also relies on hard-coded paths.

```
static GFile *
nautilus_bookmark_list_get_legacy_file (void)
{
char *filename;
GFile *file;

filename = g_build_filename (g_get_home_dir (),
                 ".gtk-bookmarks",
                 NULL);
file = g_file_new_for_path (filename);

g_free (filename);

return file;
}

static GFile *
nautilus_bookmark_list_get_file (void)
{
char *filename;
GFile *file;

filename = g_build_filename (g_get_user_config_dir (),
                 "gtk-3.0",
                 "bookmarks",
                 NULL);
file = g_file_new_for_path (filename);

g_free (filename);

return file;
}

static void
load_io_thread (GSimpleAsyncResult *result,
    GObject *object,
    GCancellable *cancellable)
{
GFile *file;
gchar *contents;
GError *error = NULL;

file = nautilus_bookmark_list_get_file ();
if (!g_file_query_exists (file, NULL)) {
    file = nautilus_bookmark_list_get_legacy_file ();
}

g_file_load_contents (file, NULL, &contents, NULL, NULL, &error);

if (error != NULL) {
    if (!g_error_matches (error, G_IO_ERROR, G_IO_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)) {
        g_warning ("Could not load bookmark file: %s\n", error->message);
    }
    g_error_free (error);
} else {
    g_simple_async_result_set_op_res_gpointer (result, contents, g_free);
}
}
```

You can see that, Nautilus first calls nautilus_bookmark_list_get_file and if it fails, it calls nautilus_bookmark_list_get_legacy_file.

Thanks in advance.
 -Sandeep

Comment: Have you looked at the Nautilus source to see how it gets the bookmark path?

Comment: Yes, I did, and to my surprise Nautilus also relies on hard-coded path. I have edited the above question to explain how Nautilus gets the bookmarks file.